# SQL SUM of values of two columns multiplied by a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

The question I need to answer is "What is the total cost of Morphine supplied to a patient called 'John Smith'?"

In my database schema I have the following schemas:

```
Patient (patientNo, patName, patAddr, DOB)
Ward (wardNo, wardName, wardType, noOfBeds)
Contains (patientNo, wardNo, admissionDate)
Drug (drugNo, drugName, costPerUnit)
Prescribed (patientNo, drugNo, unitsPerDay, startDate, finishDate)
```

I've created an example schema for the above here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wecC7cjtryKMErqPskNr41/1

How would I structure the query to multiply costPerUnit*unitsPerDay by the amount of days between startDate and finishDate without manually counting the days?

Currently I have:

```
SELECT SUM r.unitsPerDay*d.costPerUnit BETWEEN '2022-05-25' AND '2022-06-25' AS TotalCost, p.patName, d.drugName
FROM Prescribed r, Drug d, Patient p
WHERE p.patientNo=r.patientNo AND d.drugNo=r.drugNo AND r.drugNo=1001;
```

from the following:

```
insert into Drug (drugNo, drugName, costPerUnit) values (1001, 'Morphine', '25.00');
insert into Patient (patientNo, patName, patAddr, DOB) values (101, 'John Smith', '123 Street', DATE '1990-01-01');
insert into Prescribed (patientNo, drugNo, unitsPerDay, startDate, finishDate) values (101, 1001, 4, DATE '2022-05-25', DATE '2022-06-25');
```

Comment: Is that your actual schema ? `Patient` table : ` DOB varchar(4)` - Don't use `varchar` for DOB, should use `date` data type. `Drug` table : `costPerUnit integer` - you used integer as data type when your data is with decimals.

Comment: Are you really using `SQL Server`? This is not valid syntax for `SQL Server` : `values (101, 'John Smith', '123 Street', DATE '1990-01-01');`

Comment: Sorry! I'm brand new to this. I had forgotten to update the table. It should've shown: `create table Patient (patientNo integer, patName varchar(100), patAddr varchar(100), DOB varchar(10));`

So should it read: 
`create table Patient (patientNo integer, patName varchar(100), patAddr varchar(100), DOB date);`

and what should I use instead of integer for the drug table? Just `costPerUnit decimal`?

Comment: for `decimal`, you should specify the precision and scale. Example `costPerUnit decimal(10,2)`

Comment: `FROM Prescribed r, Drug d, Patient p` Evolve - no one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Is your goal to compute a value based on the prescription dates that are included in your desired timeframe (e.g., '2022-05-25' AND '2022-06-25' )? Note - your fiddle is defined for MySQL not SQL Server.

Comment: @SMor yes that’s exactly what I want to do. I’m unsure if there is something I can add in the query or if I need to calculate how many days there are myself. Sorry, I literally just started learning this last week and don’t have the best textbook.

Comment: If you just started learning from a book then can I gently suggest you find a different one. You appear to be learning some rather bad practices.

Comment: Something like this perhaps https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45f0d646d886114ae14bf5e6668b78c7?

Comment: @Charlieface Do you suggest any particular textbook/book? The one I'm "learning" from is the one assigned by my professor.... so far not impressed with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM (r.unitsPerDay*d.costPerUnit*(finishDate-startDate)) AS TotalCost, p.patName, d.drugName
FROM Prescribed r, Drug d, Patient p
WHERE p.patientNo=r.patientNo AND d.drugNo=r.drugNo AND r.drugNo=1001;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your sample data to take into account that the same drug can be prescribed to the same patient multiple times.

```sql
insert into Prescribed (patientNo, drugNo, unitsPerDay, startDate, finishDate) values (101, 1001, 4, '2022-05-25', '2022-06-25');
insert into Prescribed (patientNo, drugNo, unitsPerDay, startDate, finishDate) values (101, 1001, 2, '2022-08-1', '2022-08-10');
```

The total number of units of Morphine prescribed would be `32*4 + 10*2 = 148`. And at the cost of 25 per unit the answer should be 3700.

---

```
select sum(Drug.costPerUnit * Prescribed.unitsPerDay * (Datediff(Prescribed.finishDate,Prescribed.startDate) + 1)) as total_cost
from Patient
join Prescribed on Patient.patientNo = Prescribed.patientNo and Patient.patName = 'John Smith'
join Drug on Prescribed.drugNo = Drug.drugNo and Drug.drugName = 'Morphine';
```

| total_cost |
| --- |
| 3700 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uctHSJQyUs6aEfqhA9Hx65/1)